# Why is data being pushed into the channel but never read from the receiver goroutine?

Tags: go, channel, goroutine

I am building a daemon and I have two services that will be sending data to and from each other. Service A is what produces the data and service B a is Data Buffer service or like a queue. So from the `main.go` file, service B is instantiated and started. The `Start()` method will perform the `buffer()` function as a goroutine because this function waits for data to be passed onto a channel and I don't want the main process to halt waiting for `buffer` to complete. Then Service A is instantiated and started. It is then also "registered" with Service B.

I created a method called `RegisterWithBufferService` for Service A that creates two new channels. It will store those channels as it's own attributes and also provide them to Service B.

```
func (s *ServiceA) RegisterWithBufferService(bufService *data.DataBuffer) error {
    newIncomingChan := make(chan *data.DataFrame, 1)
    newOutgoingChan := make(chan []byte, 1)
    s.IncomingBuffChan = newIncomingChan
    s.OutgoingDataChannels = append(s.OutgoingDataChannels, newOutgoingChan)
    bufService.DataProviders[s.ServiceName()] = data.DataProviderInfo{
        IncomingChan: newOutgoingChan, //our outGoing channel is their incoming
        OutgoingChan: newIncomingChan, // our incoming channel is their outgoing
    }
    s.DataBufferService = bufService
    bufService.NewProvider <- s.ServiceName() //The DataBuffer service listens for new services and creates a new goroutine for buffering
    s.Logger.Info().Msg("Registeration completed.")
    return nil
}
```

Buffer essentially listens for incoming data from Service A, decodes it using `Decode()` and then adds it to a slice called `buf`. If the slice is greater in length than `bufferPeriod` then it will send the first item in the slice in the Outgoing channel back to Service A.

```
func (b* DataBuffer) buffer(bufferPeriod int) {
    for {
        select {
        case newProvider := <- b.NewProvider:
            b.wg.Add(1)
            /*
            newProvider is a string
            DataProviders is a map the value it returns is a struct containing the Incoming and 
            Outgoing channels for this service
            */
            p := b.DataProviders[newProvider]
            go func(prov string, in chan []byte, out chan *DataFrame) {
                defer b.wg.Done()
                var buf []*DataFrame
                for {
                    select {
                    case rawData := <-in:
                        tmp := Decode(rawData) //custom decoding function. Returns a *DataFrame
                        buf = append(buf, tmp)
                        if len(buf) < bufferPeriod {
                            b.Logger.Info().Msg("Sending decoded data out.")
                            out <- buf[0]
                            buf = buf[1:] //pop
                        }
                    case <- b.Quit:
                        return
                    }
                }
            }(newProvider, p.IncomingChan, p.OutgoingChan)
        }
    case <- b.Quit:
        return
    }
}
```

Now Service A has a method called `record` that will periodically push data to all the channels in it's `OutgoingDataChannels` attribute.

```
func (s *ServiceA) record() error {
    ...
    if atomic.LoadInt32(&s.Listeners) != 0 {
        s.Logger.Info().Msg("Sending raw data to data buffer")
        for _, outChan := range s.OutgoingDataChannels {
            outChan <- dataBytes // the receiver (Service B) is already listening and this doesn't hang
        }
        s.Logger.Info().Msg("Raw data sent and received") // The logger will output this so I know it's not hanging 
    }
}
```

The problem is that Service A seems to push the data successfully using `record` but Service B never goes into the `case rawData := <-in:` case in the `buffer` sub-goroutine. Is this because I have nested goroutines? Incase it's not clear, when Service B is started, it calls `buffer` but because it would hang otherwise, I made the call to `buffer` a goroutine. So then when Service A calls `RegisterWithBufferService`, the `buffer` goroutine creates a goroutine to listen for new data from Service B and push it back to Service A once the buffer is filled. I hope I explained it clearly.

**EDIT 1**
I've made a minimal, reproducible example.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "sync/atomic"
    "time"
)

var (
    defaultBufferingPeriod int = 3
    DefaultPollingInterval int64 = 10
)

type DataObject struct{
    Data    string
}

type DataProvider interface {
    RegisterWithBufferService(*DataBuffer) error
    ServiceName() string
}

type DataProviderInfo struct{
    IncomingChan    chan *DataObject
    OutgoingChan    chan *DataObject
}

type DataBuffer struct{
    Running         int32 //used atomically
    DataProviders   map[string]DataProviderInfo
    Quit            chan struct{}
    NewProvider     chan string
    wg              sync.WaitGroup
}

func NewDataBuffer() *DataBuffer{
    var (
        wg sync.WaitGroup
    )
    return &DataBuffer{
        DataProviders: make(map[string]DataProviderInfo),
        Quit: make(chan struct{}),
        NewProvider: make(chan string),
        wg: wg,
    }
}

func (b *DataBuffer) Start() error {
    if ok := atomic.CompareAndSwapInt32(&b.Running, 0, 1); !ok {
        return fmt.Errorf("Could not start Data Buffer Service.")
    }
    go b.buffer(defaultBufferingPeriod)
    return nil
}

func (b *DataBuffer) Stop() error {
    if ok := atomic.CompareAndSwapInt32(&b.Running, 1, 0); !ok {
        return fmt.Errorf("Could not stop Data Buffer Service.")
    }
    for _, p := range b.DataProviders {
        close(p.IncomingChan)
        close(p.OutgoingChan)
    }
    close(b.Quit)
    b.wg.Wait()
    return nil
}

// buffer creates goroutines for each incoming, outgoing data pair and decodes the incoming bytes into outgoing DataFrames
func (b *DataBuffer) buffer(bufferPeriod int) {
    for {
        select {
        case newProvider := <- b.NewProvider:
            fmt.Println("Received new Data provider.")
            if _, ok := b.DataProviders[newProvider]; ok { 
                b.wg.Add(1)
                p := b.DataProviders[newProvider]
                go func(prov string, in chan *DataObject, out chan *DataObject) {
                    defer b.wg.Done()
                    var (
                        buf []*DataObject
                    )
                    fmt.Printf("Waiting for data from: %s\n", prov)
                    for {
                        select {
                        case inData := <-in:
                            fmt.Printf("Received data from: %s\n", prov)
                            buf = append(buf, inData)
                            if len(buf) > bufferPeriod {
                                fmt.Printf("Queue is filled, sending data back to %s\n", prov)
                                out <- buf[0]
                                fmt.Println("Data Sent")
                                buf = buf[1:] //pop
                            }
                        case <- b.Quit:
                            return
                        }
                    }
                }(newProvider, p.IncomingChan, p.OutgoingChan)
            }
        case <- b.Quit:
            return
        }
    }
}

type ServiceA struct{
    Active                  int32 // atomic
    Stopping                int32 // atomic
    Recording               int32 // atomic
    Listeners               int32 // atomic
    name                    string
    QuitChan                chan struct{}
    IncomingBuffChan        chan *DataObject
    OutgoingBuffChans       []chan *DataObject
    DataBufferService       *DataBuffer
}

// A compile time check to ensure ServiceA fully implements the DataProvider interface
var _ DataProvider = (*ServiceA)(nil)

func NewServiceA() (*ServiceA, error) {
    var newSliceOutChans []chan *DataObject
    return &ServiceA{
        QuitChan:  make(chan struct{}),
        OutgoingBuffChans: newSliceOutChans,
        name:   "SERVICEA",
    }, nil
}

// Start starts the service. Returns an error if any issues occur
func (s *ServiceA) Start() error {
    atomic.StoreInt32(&s.Active, 1)
    return nil
}

// Stop stops the service. Returns an error if any issues occur
func (s *ServiceA) Stop() error {
    atomic.StoreInt32(&s.Stopping, 1)
    close(s.QuitChan)
    return nil
}

func (s *ServiceA) StartRecording(pol_int int64) error {
    if ok := atomic.CompareAndSwapInt32(&s.Recording, 0, 1); !ok {
        return fmt.Errorf("Could not start recording. Data recording already started")
    }
    ticker := time.NewTicker(time.Duration(pol_int) * time.Second)
    go func() {
        for {
            select {
            case <-ticker.C:
                fmt.Println("Time to record...")
                err := s.record()
                if err != nil {
                    return
                }
            case <-s.QuitChan:
                ticker.Stop()
                return
            }
        }
    }()
    return nil
}

func (s *ServiceA) record() error {
    current_time := time.Now()
    ct := fmt.Sprintf("%02d-%02d-%d", current_time.Day(), current_time.Month(), current_time.Year())
    dataObject := &DataObject{
        Data: ct,
    }
    if atomic.LoadInt32(&s.Listeners) != 0 {
        fmt.Println("Sending data to Data buffer...")
        for _, outChan := range s.OutgoingBuffChans {
            outChan <- dataObject // the receivers should already be listening
        }
        fmt.Println("Data sent.")
    }
    return nil
}

// RegisterWithBufferService satisfies the DataProvider interface. It provides the bufService with new incoming and outgoing channels along with a polling interval
func (s ServiceA) RegisterWithBufferService(bufService *DataBuffer) error {
    if _, ok := bufService.DataProviders[s.ServiceName()]; ok {
        return fmt.Errorf("%v data provider already registered with Data Buffer.", s.ServiceName())
    }
    newIncomingChan := make(chan *DataObject, 1)
    newOutgoingChan := make(chan *DataObject, 1)
    s.IncomingBuffChan = newIncomingChan
    s.OutgoingBuffChans = append(s.OutgoingBuffChans, newOutgoingChan)
    bufService.DataProviders[s.ServiceName()] = DataProviderInfo{
        IncomingChan: newOutgoingChan, //our outGoing channel is their incoming
        OutgoingChan: newIncomingChan, // our incoming channel is their outgoing
    }
    s.DataBufferService = bufService
    bufService.NewProvider <- s.ServiceName() //The DataBuffer service listens for new services and creates a new goroutine for buffering
    return nil
}

// ServiceName satisfies the DataProvider interface. It returns the name of the service.
func (s ServiceA) ServiceName() string {
    return s.name
}

func main() {
    var BufferedServices []DataProvider
    fmt.Println("Instantiating and Starting Data Buffer Service...")
    bufService := NewDataBuffer()
    err := bufService.Start()
    if err != nil {
        panic(fmt.Sprintf("%v", err))
    }
    defer bufService.Stop()
    fmt.Println("Data Buffer Service successfully started.")

    fmt.Println("Instantiating and Starting Service A...")
    serviceA, err := NewServiceA()
    if err != nil {
        panic(fmt.Sprintf("%v", err))
    }
    BufferedServices = append(BufferedServices, *serviceA)
    err = serviceA.Start()
    if err != nil {
        panic(fmt.Sprintf("%v", err))
    }
    defer serviceA.Stop()
    fmt.Println("Service A successfully started.")

    fmt.Println("Registering services with Data Buffer...")
    for _, s := range BufferedServices {
        _ = s.RegisterWithBufferService(bufService) // ignoring error msgs for base case
    }
    fmt.Println("Registration complete.")

    fmt.Println("Beginning recording...")
    _ = atomic.AddInt32(&serviceA.Listeners, 1)
    err = serviceA.StartRecording(DefaultPollingInterval)
    if err != nil {
        panic(fmt.Sprintf("%v", err))
    }
    for {
        select {
        case RTD := <-serviceA.IncomingBuffChan:
            fmt.Println(RTD)
        case <-serviceA.QuitChan:
            atomic.StoreInt32(&serviceA.Listeners, 0)
            bufService.Quit<-struct{}{}
        }
    }
}
```

Running on Go 1.17. When running the example, it should print the following every 10 seconds:

```
Time to record...
Sending data to Data buffer...
Data sent.
```

But then Data buffer never goes into the `inData := <-in` case.

Comment: Are you able to provide a [minimal , reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?. I can see a few potential race conditions (e.g. `bufService.DataProviders`) in what you have provided and your buffering algorithm looks suspect (why `len(buf) < bufferPeriod` - I'd expect this to fire every iteration, or never if `bufferPeriod==0`?) but without a full example its difficult to comment further.

Comment: Sure, I'll do that and mark an edit in the OP.

Comment: @Brits I've made a minimal, reproducible example. By the way, you were right about `len(buf) < bufferPeriod`, It's supposed to be `len(buf) > bufferPeriod` so then it passes the first item in the slice to the outgoing channel. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To diagnose this I changed `fmt.Println("Sending data to Data buffer...")` to `fmt.Println("Sending data to Data buffer...", s.OutgoingBuffChans)` and the output was:

```
Time to record...
Sending data to Data buffer... []
```

So you are not actually sending the data to any channels. The reason for this is:

```
func (s ServiceA) RegisterWithBufferService(bufService *DataBuffer) error {
```

As the receiver is not a pointer when you do the `s.OutgoingBuffChans = append(s.OutgoingBuffChans, newOutgoingChan)` you are changing `s.OutgoingBuffChans` in a copy of the `ServiceA` which is discarded when the function exits. To fix this change:

```
func (s ServiceA) RegisterWithBufferService(bufService *DataBuffer) error {
```

to

```
func (s *ServiceA) RegisterWithBufferService(bufService *DataBuffer) error {
```

and

```
BufferedServices = append(BufferedServices, *serviceA)
```

to

```
BufferedServices = append(BufferedServices, serviceA)
```

The amended version outputs:

```
Time to record...
Sending data to Data buffer... [0xc0000d8060]
Data sent.
Received data from: SERVICEA
Time to record...
Sending data to Data buffer... [0xc0000d8060]
Data sent.
Received data from: SERVICEA
```

So this resolves the reported issue (I would not be suprised if there are other issues but hopefully this points you in the right direction). I did notice that the code you originally posted does use a pointer receiver so that might have suffered from another issue (but its difficult to comment on code fragments in a case like this).